# Can I get out of a question ban by editing my previous questions into completely new ones?

Tags: discussion, edits, post-ban

I've been banned from asking new questions. I wanted to clean up the mess I've created and think I really understand now how to make a good question.

By editing the questions I've already asked into completely new ones, I'm able to "ask" new ones. Even though this is technically possible, is it frowned on by the community? Will I end up getting banned from asking new questions again?

Comment: 3 out of the 4 questions that I can see (i.e. are not deleted) already have answers on them. By completing changing your question, you'll invalidate those answers, so **No**, that is not ok.

Comment: Also note that there is work being done to turn complete question bans into controlled throttles instead, to encourage users to keep trying to improve their current accounts: [No one likes quitting cold turkey](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230899/163250).

Comment: Yeah, that is a reasonable one buddy. Thanks I'll consider that.

Comment: Please do not do this.  This is a poor way of avoiding the question ban and will lead to more serious bans.

Comment: I edited [your recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24302356/2982225) to make it clearer. Please feel free to rollback if you don't like the edit. Your question was unclear in it's original form -1) First paragraph was your personal info, that belong in the "About Me" of your profile, not your question body. 2) Last paragraph was also noise, which belongs in the Help section "How to write a good answer" 3) Alternate words in Bold is bad formatting, it hurts the eyes. If a person can read three paragraphs of your question, they can read the last part too, so be kind to their eyes.

Comment: These are just a few pointers, hope it helps.

Comment: Noted Payeli. You have a point on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, this counts as circumventing the ban and is therefore not allowed.

We allow you to edit your questions, but only to clarify the original question and not to change it to a completely different one. That is an abuse of the edit feature regardless of whether or not you are banned.

Comment: So even if the question is unanswered and beyond salvageable, editing it into something better is still a No? Harsh.

Comment: @rene: That would effectively be the same as deleting the question and asking a new one minus the clean slate. If we want to allow that, I'd rather that deleted questions freed up "slots" for asking new questions or something. I'm not sure what the current implementation of bans is like so I don't know how feasible such a feature would be. But most of all I'm not sure there are enough cases of users learning from their mistakes to justify allowing this versus users just repeatedly deleting and posting new questions until they run out of unanswered questions to delete.