# Old question, completely revised

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-edit

What to do with [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278601/c-compiler-for-windows-ce), [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20278601/1) about Java and IMO close-worthy because of lack of a proper question (although it got some answers), then [completely revised](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20278601/4) by the OP. Suddenly it's no longer about Java anymore! He may have found a new hobby.

"Desecrating" an existing question is blatantly against SO rules -- but even after all this time? I'd rather see it deleted altogether. Or, given that the original got some answers, should it merely be rolled back to un-desecrated state?

Comment: definitely rollback, and possibly leave a comment

Comment: Is this possibly an attempt to get around a question ban?  I mean it's the only reason I can think of for this behavior.

Comment: The OP is probably trying to work around a question ban. If it is, [this question is relevant](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261172/can-i-get-out-of-a-question-ban-by-editing-my-previous-questions-into-completely/261180#261180). If not, it should still be rolled back as it completely invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: quite possible, given the low rep of this user (I can't see if he has a large number of deleted posts). Still not an excuse is it? 

Comment: @ryanyuyu:  I sure hope not.  It's a horrible attempt at it.  It'd only hurt them more in the end.

Comment: .. Swift action has been made. Is the consensus "roll back no matter what"? I was scanning if the 'new' question got any answers as well, which would have complicated things! (In this case it didn't.)

Comment: There's only something to consider if the original question didn't get any but the new question got an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you see something like that, at the *bare minimum* roll it back.  Make a comment to the effect of why you rolled back the edit, and hopefully they'll learn the error of their ways.

If they *continue* to do that sort of pervasive editing, roll it back **and** flag for moderator attention.

If you think it should be put on hold/deleted, evaluate the quality of the answers before you make that decision.  If the answers are exemplary, then the question only needs to be cleaned up a bit.