# A user edited the question into an ENTIRELY new one several times. What should happen?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, banning

I was looking at what seemed like a typical low quality noob question, when I noticed some strange comments on it. Like this one:

> Your question title asks for how to replace pixels but your question is asking for an algorithm to create clouds, without any of your current code. We can't help you with that until you post your code.

Out of context, this is a perfectly normal comment. But the question I was seeing was:

> ### Why does it have to be -= or +=?
>
> IN java there is a constant usage of +=, -= and other similar arguments. I know they are a shortcut for var = var - 1, but why is it like that?

I looked at the revision history, and the post was **edited into a COMPLETELY new question at least 3 times** (with the *delightful* edit summary of "stuff 3"). The user only has the one question on the account.

My guess is that there is something like this going on:

[Can I get out of a question ban by editing my previous questions into completely new ones?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261172/)

I flagged a mod with this message:

> The revision history shows that this post used to be an entirely different question. The changes are very suspicious...

Two important things have happened since then:

1. The question was answered. I have no clue if the person even read the comments, or if their entire screen was blocked by their desire for rep.

Here is the answer:

> Variables often have long names, longer than just 'x' or 'y'.
>
> It would be more convenient to write `++disabledLocksCounter` than `disabledLocksCounter = disabledLocksCounter  + 1`  especially if you also have something like `enabledLocksCounters`.
>
> With just 'x' or 'y' it is also more convenient, actually. And it comes from C++ which Java was designed to resemble in form.
>
> It is completely ok to write `x = x + 1`
>
> (comments)
>
> > I did 'var = var - 1' as an example. Consider 'var = var + 10'. Why is it that 'var + 10' completly alone isn't enough? -OP
>
> -
>
> > What is there to consider about adding 10 to 'var'? -Answerer
>
> (1 more comment)

Obviously, I wasn't in the mood to up vote the answer, but then...

2. Everything was deleted. I'd be glad that they are just one step further towards a ban (because of the answer), but I don't think it matters when the user will just undelete it and change the content again.

I looked at [Drastic Question Revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260066), but the answer is not applicable in this case, because the question is already self-deleted. I am afraid that this user will just keep dodging the ban.

(If you are 10k+, you can see the train wreck here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37055328/revisions)

My question is: what's going to happen now, especially since everything was deleted? Did I do the right thing or should I do something else in the future?

The other thing is **I want everyone to know that this is happening**.

Watch out for suspicious comments. And when you're browsing the new questions page, check the date the question was asked to see if it was recently undeleted.

Comment: @RadLexus This is most certainly not the typical chameleon question. This question is more like is a tiger that changed its stripes and is now a chameleon.

Comment: @RadLexus I already visited that question. It wasn't particularly helpful because I cannot see its linked question (I need ~7,500 more rep).

Comment: You mean the question mentioned in that post? You don't need to, it's just like yours - an example.

Comment: @RadLexus Could you (or another 10k+ user) get me a picture of the revision history of the deleted question from my link? I am not able to access it.

Comment: @Eric Would you mind getting me pictures of the revision history? I can't use the link you added...

Answer (score 5):

While the general rule is "do not edit your question into something different", it is difficult to enforce across the site simply due to the massive question volume.

If you encounter this, the first thing you need to do is check the existing answers.  Do they address any of the previous revisions?

If so, then roll back to the most recent version that addresses the **oldest** answer.  If you invalidate any answers with the rollback, you should at least make sure the first answerer is protected.  It would be nice if you left a comment on any of the answers the address subsequent revisions and advise them of the change so they can fix or delete their answers.

But if there are no answers that address previous revisions of the question, you have found a gray area of the guidelines.  If you roll back, you'll be rolling back to an older (and presumably uninteresting) question.  So you have 2 options - rollback or not.  To figure out which, ask yourself:

- Is the new question of good quality?  Does it contain all of the components of a good questions?  If so, you may choose to upvote it and ignore the past history.  Or if not, then you may downvote it.
- Is the new question even on-topic?  This is where it is tough.

  - If the old question was on-topic and acceptable quality then roll it back to the most recent "good" version.
  - Are none of the old versions on-topic?  Then just vote to close the current question.  No sense rolling back just to close it.

The general answer is that you should handle the question best that fits the community and use common sense.  If it is a good on-topic question without answers to address previous revisions, then you should just accept the fact that the OP changed the question.  But if the edits made the post worse (or did not improve the on-topicness of the post), or invalidated answers, then you should roll back the edit.

---

I have completely avoided the issue of old comments.  But if you are worried about comments, my opinion is that comments are intended to be "temporary".  You should never worry about invalidating comments.  If there are no answers, but a few comments addressing the original question, then the comments should be flagged for removal (this is assuming the new question is on-topic and of **good** quality).  Replacing a bad question with a different bad question with a different bad question just needs to be closed/downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, not everyone needs to know what's going on.  You've already alerted the moderators to what's going on and that's all you really need to notify.

Second, if you do run into this scenario, the best thing to do is to flag for moderator attention *and* roll the edit back to avoid invalidating any existing answers, the latter of which you can do due to you [being > 2K reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: While this is good advice in general, the question only had the one answer that was added during its most recent revision. Rolling it back now (if it weren't deleted) would have invalidated that answer for sure.