# Backup questions for use when banned

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, post-ban, gamification

Let's say there was someone named Joe. He's about to be banned from asking questions, so he makes a plan to circumvent the system when it happens. First, he asks a bunch of questions filled with gibberish content. He quickly deletes all of them so nobody will find out about his "trick". Those questions will be "backup questions" for use during a question-ban. Later on, Joe encounters a programming problem, so he goes to ask a question. He finds out that he got question-banned. But since he has all those "backup questions," he can still ask questions in a way. He edits one of his "backup questions." He replaces the gibberish with meaningful content that describes his programming problem. Finally, he un-deletes the question. What Joe did was basically the same as asking a new question.

What if a user circumvents a question-ban by using this "backup questions" technique? Not that I would do that...

**EDIT:** *this question is not a duplicate of [Drastic Question Revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260066/drastic-question-revision), because this question is addressing question-bans, while the other one only asks about drastic edits to a question without taking the circumvention of bans into account.*

Comment: Joe.... Just dont do that, hypothetically speaking,of course

Comment: @Laurel:  That answers what a user with edit privileges should do should they encounter it.  This question is asking what the consequences of such a thing would be, which may well be above anyone who's not a moderator's pay grade to answer.

Comment: @Makoto Fine, we should reopen [my question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322616) so we can close as a duplicate of that. Because I asked this exact thing before.

Comment: This is a site full of people who are excessively good at recognising patterns and smelling fishy things from a mile away. Every question has a edit history. The chances of getting away with that are exceedingly small.

Comment: *"He's about to be banned from asking questions, so he makes a plan to circumvent the system....."* i don't need to read any more. Joe clearly isn't going to add anything meaningful to the community since he see's that he's going to be banned but rather work towards avoid the ban he works towards circumventing it when it happens. it's one thing for a programmer to set ways to bypass limitation, it's another thing to do that to limitations imposed by bad conduct. extreme example it's like if i beat my wfie, rather that change my ways i just get another wife who wont rat on me to the police

Comment: Well, sometimes the MSO community sacrifices the importance of the free communication to some other goals. I think you shouldn't worry on it, talking about ideas to change something are generally good, even if they are rejected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not gonna fly since each question has an [edit history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/325527/1) attached to it.  It would likely sound more alarms than it would allow them to fly under the radar, and it would likely harm them greatly from the question ban's perspective.

If one were to attempt to do this, my advice would be to **not**, since there's a very high chance that a diligent user will put two and two together and work out what's going on.

Oh, and the user will likely encounter *harsher* bans.

One thing I forgot to mention:  a moderator can view all users' deleted posts, and it will likely serve as an even *greater* red flag as to what's going on should the user's posts be flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: Between the question ban algorithm, various automatic flags that could be tripped and an attentive community - Joe is going to find this hard to pull off. Also, if Joe still has an account afterwards, they're not going to be using it for a while...