# How to handle edited question that is another question

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38431749/4519059) that was edited by OP, and whole of question was changed.
I add below comment for OP, But am I in a right way?

> As I can see you changed your question to a new question, So please delete your question and ask another one ;).

I think to vote it down in next step then as following to this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260069/4519059) roll it back.

---

I think OP thought if he delete then edit then undelete his post it is a valid way as you can see in [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38431749/revisions).

Comment: If it doesn't invalidate any existing answers this is OK. It might be the only way question banned users have to ask a better question.

Comment: @rene Unless, we hit the cases where OP tries to **undergo** a question ban (said without spotting the question in question).

Comment: Related: [Backup questions for use when banned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325527/backup-questions-for-use-when-banned)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hmm, no. They are question banned. We tell them to improve existing posts. If such question doesn't have answers but they see no fit in  editing the current question into shape but instead replace it with a better one, how does that undergo a q-ban? Notice the key is no existing answers. Worst what will happen in that case is that it invalidates comments.

Comment: @rene Well, I had a look now. This particular case is OK.  But I've seen questions that were used as a placeholding point and changed topics completely, I think the latter is frowned upon.

Comment: @rene /OT and what's that flower BTW? May want to answer in SOCVR.

Comment: Yep, agree on that. Btw, due to the facts I don't think the dupe holds @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Thanks and In order to related question IMHO,If I roll it back without any commenting that will not be so nice to OP, If I roll it back directly after commenting that also will not be so nice to OP, So I prefer to wait for a while then roll it back ;).